# Swift - Force set cell size whie UITableViewAutomaticDimension is set

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have an auto-resizing table and I want to forcely set some cells' height to display the header only.

I have this on my code:

```
tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 140
```

And, I tried adding the snippet below but the auto-resizing effect stopped working:

```
tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat
```

Please find the below screenshot of the table that I want to accomplish.

[image]

Comment: why use the heightForRowAtIndexPath ?

Comment: Does auto-resize stop working if you return super.tableView(tableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath: indexPath) for rows you don't want to hide?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to continue make things your way:

1. remove `tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension`, because after implementing `heightForRowAtIndexPath` it does nothing.
2. implement `heightForRowAtIndexPath` method, which will return special height for chosen cells and for the others - `UITableViewAutomaticDimension`

Comment: It worked! Thank you so much for the answer, @MaksymMusiienko. It helped me a lot